# Print a 10x10 times table

Tags: c++, array

I have been on the C++ learning grind for the last 2 weeks using caveofprogramming videos so don't judge too hard if this seems like a dumb question.

My last lesson covered arrays and the assignment was to make a 10x10 times table using multidimensional arrays. I succeeded in making this times table but with my knowledge I had to type type out each integer. Is this the best way to handle this scenario or is there a way that I could calculate most of the integers without typing out 10 lines of arrays?

```
#include<iostream>
#include<Windows.h>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int animals[10][10] = {
        {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10},
        {2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18,20},
        {3,6,9,12,15,18,21,24,27,30},
        {4,8,12,16,20,24,28,32,36,40},
        {5,10,16,20,25,30,35,40,45,50},
        {6,12,18,24,30,36,42,48,54,60},
        {7,14,21,28,35,42,49,56,63,70},
        {8,16,24,32,40,48,56,64,72,80},
        {9,18,27,36,45,54,63,72,81,90},
        {10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100},
    };                                          
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
            cout << animals[i][j] << " " << flush;
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're sure about the data that you want in your array, like the one you mentioned, each row is an arithmetic progression, then this can be done easily using loop.

```
int n = 10, m = 10; //you can take this as user input
int animals[n][m];
int indexRow, indexColumn;
for (indexRow = 0; indexRow < n ; indexRow++) {
    for (indexColumn = 0; indexColumn < m; indexColumn++) {
        animals[indexRow][indexColumn] = (indexRow + 1) + (indexColumn)*(indexRow + 1);
    }
}
```

What we have done here is, used formula of `nth term` of an arithmetic progression while setting values for each row. As you see, first element of each `row` is `it's index number + 1`, and `nth` term in the series is `column's index number + 1` So we applied the following formula:

```
a + (n-1)d
```

where `a` is the first term of the series, `n` refers to the `nth` term, and `d` is the common difference.

After applying the above, we can see the array as:

```
for (indexRow = 0; indexRow < n ; indexRow++) {
    for (indexColumn = 0; indexColumn < m; indexColumn++) {
        cout << animals[indexRow][indexColumn] << " " << flush;
    }
}
```

which prints expected output.

Answer (score 2):

`animals` is an, um, *unconventional* name for a table of products.

There doesn't seem to be any compelling need to have the array, though - just print out the values as you reach them:

```
for (int i = 1;  i <= 10;  ++i) {
    for (int j = 1; j <= 10;  ++j) {
        std::cout << i * j << " ";
    }
    std::cout << '\n';
}
```

It would be nice to make the numbers line up (since it's supposed to be a *table*).  We can do this using the I/O manipulator `std::setw()` (found in `<iomanip>`).  That would give the resulting complete program:

```
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    static constexpr int limit = 10;
    for (int i = 1;  i <= limit;  ++i) {
        for (int j = 1;  j <= limit;  ++j) {
            std::cout << std::setw(4)
                      << i * j;
        }
        std::cout << '\n';
    }
}
```

Some other observations, incorporated above:

- Avoid `using namespace std`, especially at file scope.
- Returning 0 from `main()` is optional; in the main function you're allowed to run off the end, and a return value of zero is inferred.  That's not allowed in any other value-returning function, of course.
- Prefer to use prefix `++` and `--` when the value isn't used.  Although that likely doesn't affect your code applying them to `int`, it can save a costly copy with some types, so it's a good habit to cultivate.
- There's no need to flush the output (with `std::flush` or `std::endl`).  Just let the buffering do its job.
- When I was at school, multiplication tables went up to 12.  Perhaps that's different where/when you are, though (I guess decimal currency reduces the need to have multiples of 11 and 12 learnt by rote?).  We  can use a named constant so we can easily change the limit and still have a square table.

Answer (score 1):

The two previous answers create the array at run-time.  I want to add the fact that you can use `constexpr` to compute it at *compile time* exactly as if you had typed it in.

Also, [Don’t](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721) write `using namespace std;`.

You should use just output `\n` instead of using `endl`.  And your explicit call to `flush` is not necessary and just slows it down.

Don't include `<windows.h>` when your code only uses standard C++ and doesn't call any Windows API.

Answer (score 0):

Even though devRabbit's answer yields the right answer, it makes more sense to me to create a times table with multiplication.

```cpp
const int n = 10, m = 10;
int animals[n][m];
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    for(int j = 0; j < m; j++)
    {
        animals[i][j] = (i + 1)*(j + 1);
    }
}
```

Also, when printing, the numbers will be lined up nicely if you use a tab instead of a space to separate them.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense now that I see it. Thank you for the answer!